# How to convert specific column values from character vectors to numeric vectors?

Tags: r, character, numeric, dplyr, tibble

I have a .csv file where I want to convert all columns to numerics. I have an example below for my tibble.
The .csv file contains coordinates, x and y, that correspond to a specific location or "station" out in the ocean.
I would like to make it so that the station labeled in the columns (currently characters) are returned as numerics.

```
grinches_tibble2$station <- as.numeric(grinches_tibble2$station, 
                                                             c(1 = "G9A",
                                                               2 = "G9B",
                                                               3 = "G10A",
                                                               4 = "G11D",
                                                               5 = "G11E",
                                                               6 = "G12A",
                                                               7 = "G11A", 
                                                               8 = "G12D", 
                                                               9 = "G13A", 
                                                               10 = "G13B"))
```

So, in my tibble the stations are labeled G9A, G10A, etc.
I would like them to read numbers instead where G9A is a 1 instead. So station G9A would now be station 1. Please, anything will help.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we have a data like this:

```
library(dplyr)
#Data
Data <- data.frame(station=c("G9A","G9B","G10A","G11D","G11E",
                             "G12A","G11A","G12D","G13A", "G13B"),
                   stringsAsFactors = F)
Data
   station
1      G9A
2      G9B
3     G10A
4     G11D
5     G11E
6     G12A
7     G11A
8     G12D
9     G13A
10    G13B
```

You can get something close to what you expect using `dplyr` with `mutate()` and `as.numeric()` as well as `as.factor()`:

```
#Code
new <- Data %>%
  mutate(station=factor(station,levels = unique(station),ordered = T)) %>%
  mutate(station2=as.numeric(as.factor(station)))
```

Output:

```
   station station2
1      G9A        1
2      G9B        2
3     G10A        3
4     G11D        4
5     G11E        5
6     G12A        6
7     G11A        7
8     G12D        8
9     G13A        9
10    G13B       10
```